# using "at" specification in Margins (problem with factors)

Tags: r, marginal-effects

Does anybody know if (or when?) we can use the “at” specification for factor variables in the Margins Package?

According to the Margins [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) (dated 2018-05-22), this is not always possible "yet". I quote from the vignette below:

*“A really nice feature of Stata’s margins command is that it handles factor variables gracefully. This functionality is difficult to emulate in R, but the margins() function does its best. …. margins() recognizes the factor and displays the marginal effect for each level of the factor separately. (Caveat: this may not work with certain “at” specifications, yet.)”*

Indeed, I get an error when I try with my logistic regression that relies entirely on   independent variables that are factors (e.g., "LOC" in code below).

> margins(me.model.glm, at = list(LOC = 0:1))

**Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) :
'names' attribute [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) must be the same length as the vector [0]**

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
margins(me.model.glm, at = list(LOC = c("0","1"))
```

That worked for me in an analogous situation. Note that if I just put in one value for the factor variable, like

```
margins(me.model.glm, at = list(LOC = "0"))
```

I get an error. I must provide values for each level of the factor variable

Comment: I had the same issue with a factor and this worked for me. I needed the 'c()' around the list. Note the first chunk of code needs a closing bracket.